# Exclude a string from ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, match, google-query-language

So i'm using ARRAYFORMULA to grab a list of strings from another sheet. I only want strings which don't contain "USD". How do I program my cell to collect data which excludes the string "USD"?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Account!A4:A100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A4:A100; NOT(REGEXMATCH(A4:A100&""; "USD")))
```